# Tomcat Native Clustering Apache geronimo 3.0.1 not working

Tags: java, apache, geronimo

I have two linux machines with geronimo 3.0.1 running on them.

My requirement is to cluster the application and do an automatic deployment/un-deployment on other machine once an application is deployed on any machine.

For this I have configured Tomcat Native clustering in Apache geronimo 3.0.1 with following configuration on both servers.

```
<Host name="${ServerHostname}" appBase=""
                  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
                  xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

                  <Cluster channelSendOptions="8" className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster">
                        <Manager channelSendOptions="6" className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" mapSendOptions="6" name="cluster1" notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
                        <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
                            <Membership address="228.0.0.4" className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService" dropTime="3000" frequency="500" port="45564"/>
                            <Receiver address="auto" autoBind="100" className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" maxThreads="6" port="4000" selectorTimeout="5000"/>
                            <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
                                <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
                            </Sender>
                            <Interceptor className="org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.interceptor.DisableMcastInterceptor"/>
                            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector" interval="60"/>
                            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.StaticMembershipInterceptor">
                               <Member UniqueId="{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}" domain="mapp01" host="10.9.90.102" port="5002" securePort="-1"/>    
                            </Interceptor>
                            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
                            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>
                        </Channel>
                        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=".*\.gif;.*\.js;.*\.jpg;.*\.png;.*\.htm;.*\.html;.*\.css;.*\.txt;"/>
                        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
                        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
                        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
               </Cluster>
```

When I restarted server and deployed a war file on one server , the app was not clustered and deployed to other server automatically.In logs I found these two lines related to clustering

```
[TomcatModuleBuilder] No clustering builders configured: app will not be clustered 
[DeltaManager] Manager [/Test]: skipping state transfer. No members active in cluster
```

group.

I didn't get any solution to these in apache forums and documentation.

Is there any solution available to this?